# How to get data from ExtensionObject + WCF

Tags: wcf

I am getting some data in the form ExtensionData in Client side. However, it is coming properly in the server side(means the class properties as expected) But how to get the data from the Extension object is not known to me. I am new to WCF and is using C#

Hewlp needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to need to use  [Message Inspectors](http://problog.jamespritz.com/2009/05/17/custom-headers-in-wcf.aspx).

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717047.aspx)